# Traversing a hierarchy with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel-formula, formula, libreoffice-calc

I have the following dataset:

```
ID     Name         Level  DirectBoss
E1     MegaBoss         1        
E2     SuperBoss1       2          E1
E3     SuperBoss2       2          E1
E4     RegularBoss1     3          E2
E5     RegularBoss2     3          E2
E6     RegularBoss3     3          E1
E7     John             4          E5
E8     Mary             4          E6
```

It defines a pretty conventional hierarchy: a bunch of employees identified by an ID, their name, which level they are placed in the hierarchy, and who is their direct boss.

My problem is that I need to find out who's the boss of a particular employee, but at an specific level. In this example, John's level 1 boss is MegaBoss, level 2 is SuperBoss1, and level 3 would be its direct boss, RegularBoss2.

How could I calculate this with a formula? It looks like a job for some kind of recursive VLOOKUP: I would look for John's direct boss, then for his boss's boss, and stop when I've got to the desired level. But of course conventional VLOOKUP doesn't work this way. Is there some way to achieve this result?

Thanks!

Comment: this can be done using a few helper columns (depends on the number of levels) and `INDEX` formula. Just wondering how would you determine the look up criteria, say John has three bosses before him but Mary has only two, so for instance would you agree that their ultimate boss would be megaboss, 2nd level boss is E2 (for John) and E6 (for Mary), and 3rd level boss is E2 for John but none for Mary. So if you look up 2nd level boss for John and Mary, it should return SuperBoss1 and RegularBoss3 even though they are at different level.

Comment: If you can use **Power Pivot** or **Power BI**, in which the `PATH()` function can lay out the level-chain for each employee, which will make it easily for you to find the boss at the desired level. The first answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561542/power-query-child-hierarcy) has explained it well although the question was different to yours. I was able to do it using **Power Query** with the help of a [custom function](https://pivotalbi.com/dynamically-flatten-a-parent-child-hierarchy-using-power-query-m/). Let me know if you want to see a demo answer.